# Creating minified js files using Grunt for AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have an existing AngularJS project with tonnes of controllers and HTML pages. I need to use Grunt to create minified JS files. The issue is I am not able to work with Grunt. Whenever I run grunt commands I always get the error:

> 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I tried running

> npm install
>   npm install -g
>   npm install -g grunt-cli
>   npm install grunt --save-dev

None of the above commands work for me. Can someone please point out what is the step by step process to work with Grunt? Here is what the package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "grunt-cache-bust",
  "description": "Bust static assets from the cache using content hashing",
  "version": "0.6.0",
  "author": "Ben Holland <hi@benholland.me>",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust.git"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust/blob/master/LICENSE-MIT"
    }
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "~0.18.0",
    "css": "~2.2.0",
    "flatten": "~0.0.1",
    "path-is-absolute": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "grunt",
    "grunt plugin",
    "cache",
    "bust",
    "bust assets"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. download and install nodejs: https://nodejs.org/en/
2. download and install npm https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm
3. install Grunt CLI globally using npm: `npm install -g grunt-cli`
4. open your project folder: `cd <your_project>`
5. install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder:`npm install`

Check that everything is installed:

1. `node -v` shows version of node
2. `npm -v` shows version of npm
3. `grunt -V` ("V" is in uppercase here) shows version of grunt

After that you have to create `Gruntfile.js` to minify your js files. Register grunt task there like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
   ... 
]);
```

And use npm package [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify). 
Also you can use [grunt-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-babel) if it is needed with `minified` option.